# put scroll on Bokeh Dropdown choices

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to put scroll for Bokeh dropdown when there are many options? For example, in the following image, I would like to have 5 options at a time, and be able to scroll down to other options when needed. That would be great if you could provide a working example. Here is a an example for a dropdown.

[image]

```
from bokeh.models import Dropdown

mymenu = [(str(i), str(i)) for i in range(1, 10)]

dd = Dropdown(label="DropDown Label",
                     button_type="warning", menu=mymenu, width=150)

show(ddmsn)
```

I tried putting a height for the DropDown but it seems it only takes into account the height of the label.

Comment: I know, its a long time ago you asked this question... But did you came across a solution? I have exactly the same problem haveing around 30 Options to choose fron in my dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Select instead of DropDown

Comment: The user specifically asked for assistance with DropDown, perhaps there is a functional reason for it.  Could you provide more context for your answer regarding why it is better or solves the problem?