# Bokeh Server: Trouble attaching callback to glyph tap e.g. a circle?

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been trying to call a python function when a glyph is clicked. I've tried this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/50499396/8925535 and this https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/g/bokeh/c/zVzLyvJFWtE/m/eRugLfUuAAAJ but still my callback never gets called. Here's my code

```
from bokeh.models import Slider, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import d3

from numpy.random import random

#Create data for the plot
initial_points = 5
data = {'x': random(initial_points),
        'y': random(initial_points)
       }

source = ColumnDataSource(data = {'x': random(initial_points), 'y': random(initial_points)})

plot = figure(title = "Random scatter plot generator", plot_height=750, plot_width=750, 
        tools="tap")
plot.circle(x = 'x', y = 'y', source = source,  color='green', size=20, alpha=0.5)

slider_widget = Slider(start = 0, end = 20, step = 2, value = initial_points, title = 'Slide 
     right to increase number of points')

def slider_callback(attr, old, new):
    points = slider_widget.value
    source.data = {'x': random(points), 'y': random(points)}
slider_widget.on_change('value', slider_callback)

def tap_callback(attr, old, new):
    print('Here mate')

source.on_change('selected', tap_callback)

layout = row(slider_widget, plot)
curdoc().add_root(layout)
```

The callback function in question is ***tap_callback***.
I'd really love to see *"Here mate"* printed in terminal after clicking a glyph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```py
source.on_change('selected', tap_callback)
```

with

```py
source.selected.on_change('indices', tap_callback)
```

Comment: What if the source was say a `graph.node_renderer.data_source`?

Comment: It doesn't...the only property available is the the `selected` property, and not the `indices` property. And that doesn't work.

Comment: "The only property available is the `selected` property" - but that's exactly what my answer suggests using? It should be `graph.node_renderer.data_source.selected.on_change('indices', tap_callback)`

Comment: Welll I meant the first param to the `on_change` method. I finally found the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58449409/8925535

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The first parameter is `'indices'`, and it works perfectly for me for graphs with the latest Bokeh version. But I'm glad you got it working either way.